# Let $A\subseteq X$ be fixed non-empty subset of $X$. Let $B$ be set of subsets of $X$ that contains $A$. So, what can you say about $A\cap B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A\subseteq X$ be fixed non-empty subset of $X$. Let $B$ be set of subsets of $X$ that contains $A$. So, what can you say about $A\cap B$?

I think, it is $A\cap B=A$, right?

Comment: Usually $A\cap B$ will be empty...elements of $B$ are subsets of $X$, not elements of $X$.  But I'm not sure you've stated your question the way you meant to.

Comment: To start with, what does "contains" mean? Do you mean $$B=\{x\in X:A\in x\}$$ or do you mean $$B=\{x\in X:A\subseteq x\}?$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\{1,2\}$ and $A=\{1\}$. Then $B=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

In general, $B$ contains *sets* containing $A$. By definition, $A$ cannot contain any set like $\{A\}$